# How to use MessagePack-CSharp with string JSON? Not is CLI, is neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp

Tags: c#, json, msgpack

```
using MessagePack;
[MessagePackObject]
public class CPegar_ids
{
    [Key(0)]
    public string operationName { get; set; }
    [Key(1)]
    public Variables variables { get; set; }
    [Key(2)]
    public string query { get; set; }
}

[MessagePackObject]
public class Variables
{
    [Key(0)]
    public object activeType { get; set; }
    [Key(1)]
    public string[] instruments { get; set; }
    [Key(2)]
    public string leverageInstrument { get; set; }
    [Key(3)]
    public int userGroupID { get; set; }
    [Key(4)]
    public string sortField { get; set; }
    [Key(5)]
    public string sortDirection { get; set; }
    [Key(6)]
    public int limit { get; set; }
    [Key(7)]
    public int offset { get; set; }
}
string json_data = @"
{
  ""operationName"": ""GetAssets"",
  ""variables"": {
    ""activeType"": null,
    ""instruments"": [
      ""BinaryOption"",
      ""DigitalOption"",
      ""FxOption"",
      ""TurboOption""
    ],
    ""leverageInstrument"": ""BinaryOption"",
    ""userGroupID"": 193,
    ""sortField"": ""Name"",
    ""sortDirection"": ""Ascending"",
    ""limit"": 20,
    ""offset"": 0
  },
  ""query"": """"
}
";

var ob_ids = MessagePackSerializer.Deserialize<CPegar_ids>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json_data ));

Console.WriteLine($" IDS OB: {ob_ids.GetType()}");
```

https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp

I'm downloading JSON with HttpWebRequest, which returns a var string. I want to use this string to Deserialize with MessagePackSerializer. I've tried several different ways, with Utf8Json I can do it, but with this MessagePack I can't. I want to use MessagePack because it is much faster.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like MessageBack have their own notation which is not JSON. But you're trying to deserialize Json into their custom notation which fails for obvious reasons. They seem to keep it small an compact by using more unicode in place of standard characters like JSON.

see https://msgpack.org/index.html

This is why you're not going to make it work putting in a JSON string and trying to deserialize it. If you're looking for faster JSON options there are a few other common alternatives to Newtonsoft Json.NET such as fastJSON https://github.com/mgholam/fastJSON

Reversing your sample code we can get an example of what the serialized values look like:

```
var myObject = new CPegar_ids {
    operationName = "GetAssets",
    variables = new Variables {
        activeType = null,
        instruments = new string[] {
            "BinaryOption",
            "DigitalOption",
            "TurboOption"
        },
        leverageInstrument = "BinaryOption",
        userGroupID = 193,
        sortField = "Name",
        sortDirection = "Ascending",
        limit = 20,
        offset = 0
    },
    query = ""
};

var bytes = MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(myObject);
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes));
```

the output of which is:
��operationName�GetAssets�variables��activeType��instruments��BinaryOption�DigitalOption�TurboOption�leverageInstrument�BinaryOption�userGroupID���sortField�Name�sortDirection�Ascending�limit14�offset00�query�

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a good explanation on why it is not working. But there is a way to make it work instead of using `Key(int index)` attribute we will use `Key(string propertyName)` attribute.

> Should you use an indexed (int) key or a string key? We recommend
> using indexed keys for faster serialization and a more compact binary
> representation than string keys. [Reference.](https://github.com/neuecc/MessagePack-CSharp)

OBJECTS

```
[MessagePackObject]
public class CPegar_ids
{
    [Key("operationName")]
    public string operationName { get; set; }
    [Key("variables")]
    public Variables variables { get; set; }
    [Key("query")]
    public string query { get; set; }
}

[MessagePackObject]
public class Variables
{
    [Key("activeType")]
    public object activeType { get; set; }
    [Key("instruments")]
    public string[] instruments { get; set; }
    [Key("leverageInstrument")]
    public string leverageInstrument { get; set; }
    [Key("userGroupID")]
    public int userGroupID { get; set; }
    [Key("sortField")]
    public string sortField { get; set; }
    [Key("sortDirection")]
    public string sortDirection { get; set; }
    [Key("limit")]
    public int limit { get; set; }
    [Key("offset")]
    public int offset { get; set; }
}
```

SERIALIZATION

```
var jsonByteArray = MessagePackSerializer.ConvertFromJson(File.ReadAllText("json1.json"));
CPegar_ids  ob_ids = MessagePackSerializer.Deserialize<CPegar_ids>(jsonByteArray);
```

Comment: Worth keeping in mind that if this does work, It's going to be converting from JSON to MessagePack and then from MessagePack into the .Net object. Which is likely much slower than just going directly from JSON to .Net. Op mentions they want to use MessagePack for performance which is why I comment.